# Error after trying to send a command to a website console

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

login_script is a command i want to send to website console

this is the error: selenium.common.exceptions.JavascriptException: Message: javascript error: missing ) after argument list

```
login_script = '''
function login(token) {{
setInterval(() =\> {{
document.body.appendChild(document.createElement `iframe`).contentWindow.localStorage.token = `"${{token}}"`
}}, 50);
setTimeout(() =\> {{
location.reload();
}}, 2500);
}}

login('{}');
'''

for token in gettokens.token_list:
driver.get("https://discord.com/login")
driver.execute_script("console.log(`" + login_script.format(token) + "`);")
time.sleep(10)
```

ignore this line <kbd>for token in gettokens.token_list:</kbd>